# Azure Managed Service Identity endpoint missing in App Service for Containers

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-app-service-plans, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to deploy my app to Azure App Service for Containers, using the docker-compose preview. The deployment configuration is as follows:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  auth:
    image: myorg/myimage
    environment:
      - MyOrg__Hosting__PathBase=/auth
      - ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true
      - ConnectionStrings__AuthenticationDatabase
  # other services not important for this question
```

Within that deployment, I need to access Azure Key Vault, with which I have integrated my app via the Key Vault Configuration provider, as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources):

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
        azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

    config.AddAzureKeyVault(
        $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVault:Name"]}.vault.azure.net/",
        keyVaultClient,
        DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

My Azure Key Vault has the appropriate access policy set, and from the Kudu pages it seems that the `MSI_ENDPOINT` and `MSI_SECRET` environment variables have been set in the runtime environment. However, the Key Vault configuration provider repeatedly fails to connect to Key Vault with the error:

> ```
> Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: 
> Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, 
> Authority: https://login.windows.net/6e5e63bd-f497-4f71-a6f4-9d29200a8a61. Exception 
> Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
> 2020-02-21T18:27:27.024474350Z Parameters: 
> Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, 
> Authority: https://login.windows.net/6e5e63bd-f497-4f71-a6f4-9d29200a8a61. Exception 
> Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Unable to connect to the Managed Service Identity (MSI) endpoint. Please check that you are running on an Azure resource that has MSI setup.
> 2020-02-21T18:27:27.024479550Z Parameters: 
> Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, 
> Authority: https://login.windows.net/6e5e63bd-f497-4f71-a6f4-9d29200a8a61. Exception 
> Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not set.
> 2020-02-21T18:27:27.024483550Z Parameters: 
> Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, 
> Authority: https://login.windows.net/6e5e63bd-f497-4f71-a6f4-9d29200a8a61. Exception 
> Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. No such file or directory
> ```

The first of those three methods clearly indicates that MSI is not available for some rean.

I've added a manual request for debugging purposes taken from [the documentation on Managed Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources):

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetToken(string resource, string apiversion)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var msiEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSI_ENDPOINT") ?? "MSI_ENDPOINT is not set!";
    Log.Logger.Debug("MSI_ENDPOINT is {MsiEndpoint}", msiEndpoint);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Secret", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MSI_SECRET"));
    return await client.GetAsync(String.Format("{0}/?resource={1}&api-version={2}", msiEndpoint, resource, apiversion));
}
```

and I can clearly see in my application logs the line `MSI_ENDPOINT is` - so it's set, but empty or whitespace. This is supported by the `InvalidOperationException` thrown by the debugging request, stating that "An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set."

I've tried disabling and re-enabling the system-assigned identity, restarting my App Service, and triple-checking the Key Vault access policies, all to no avail. At this point, I think I can only assume that the `MSI_*` environment variables aren't being passed on to the container(s) by the runtime, and I'm not sure why that would be.

---

**Update:** I have now also tried listing the `MSI_*` environment variables in the `environment` map in my docker-compose config, and that also didn't have any effect.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Currently stuck at the exact same issue.

Answer (score 3):

For your issue, I think you missed two steps for the Managed identity of the Web App for Container.

One is that you need to enable the Managed identity first. For example, you use the type system assigned of Managed identity. The enable it like this:

[image]

Then the environment variables `MSI_ENDPOINT` and `MSI_SECRET` will display like this:

[image]

Another is that if you need to use the Managed identity to access the key vault, you need to grant your Managed identity enough permissions. You can follow the steps in [Assign a managed identity access to a resource by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/howto-assign-access-portal).

Comment: Thanks Charles. I have enabled the system-assigned identity, and I see the environment variables defined per your second screenshot. Within my container, though, these environment variables are not set or are empty.

Comment: I just checked my KeyVault's RBAC permissions, and found that the web app didn't have a Reader role assignment for that resource. Unfortunately even after adding that assignment, I still see the same error 

Comment: @alastairs Not only the permission for the key vault. You need also to set the access policy, for example, the secrets access control. You can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-identity).

Comment: @alastairs Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: the access policy on the resources are set appropriately for the app: get and list secrets. In fact, it was the page you linked to which I followed to set this up in the first place 

Comment: @alastairs Do you allow the network of your Web app in the key vault firewall?

Comment: the KeyVault is currently set to allow access from all networks, to eliminate this as a possibility.